# Sorting os.listdir()'s arbitrary order for desired output

Tags: python, list, sorting

[Image of Txt Files in Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM7UP.png)
I currently possess a folder with .txt files that are named "Month day.txt"

Running os.listdir('.') outputs in this order:

```
["April 30.txt", "April 4.txt", "May 1.txt", "May 10.txt", "May 11.txt", "May 2.txt"]
```

The order I would like to output:

```
["April 4.txt", "April 30.txt", "May 1.txt", "May 2.txt", "May 10.txt", "May 11.txt"]
```

To get it, I have a feeling to somehow sort the names by numbers first and then alphabetical.
I spent the last hour researching similar problems, and the best I was able to find was this.

```
files = os.listdir('.')
re_pattern = re.compile('.+?(\d+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9+])')
files_ordered = sorted(files, key=lambda x: int(re_pattern.match(x).groups()[0]))
```

Which I understood used a regex to capture the digits and used it as a key for sorting,
which sensibly arranged the files based on the numbers only. (May 12, April 13, etc)
Furthermore, I tried to mess around with it using capture groups on the month, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually sort this rather easily with the `datetime` module.

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
a = ["April 30.txt", "April 4.txt", "May 1.txt", "May 10.txt", "May 11.txt", "May 2.txt"]

b = sorted(a,key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[:-4], "%B %d"))
print(b)
```

output:

```
['April 4.txt', 'April 30.txt', 'May 1.txt', 'May 2.txt', 'May 10.txt', 'May 11.txt']
```

What this does is it takes the sequence of filenames, and for each filename it removes the extension `.txt`  and then converts the remaining date string into a date object with `datetime.strptime` function.  The builtin sorted function automatically knows how to sot date objects.

If you were in a situation where you had multiple file extensions with different lengths, e.g.  `.txt` , `.json`  instead of using x[:-4] you could instead use `os.path.splitext(x)[0]`  or use regex to isolate and remove the file extension.

Comment: +1 Worked like a charm. For clarification sake,  would you mind explaining to me what the datetime.strptime(x[:-4], "%B %d") did? i understood the %B %d part, but not the x[:-4]

Comment: I just added an explanation... the [:-4] is removing the file extension @zen  you could also use something like os.path.splitext(x)[0] if you didn't already know in advance how many characters the file extension was.